# Removing Mixins When Compiling

Tags: css, compilation, sass, stylesheet, mixins

I've been doing some research on this and haven't been able to come up with anything so far (and maybe that's my answer), but I thought I'd reach out on here to see if anyone might know anything about this.

I'm using Sass for my stylesheets in a project and I was wondering if there is a way to compile everything twice: once with all mixins present and a second time without a certain mixin. In this case, the mixin I'm curious to omit is one that I've written to deal with media queries at certain breakpoints, which I utilize at various points throughout my stylesheet to keep all relevant styles bundled together rather than in a separate "responsive" stylesheet. However, I'd like to test certain things by removing all responsive styling at times, hence the desire to remove these for one set and keep them in another and be able to switch back and forth as needed.

For example, I might have some styling for a page title like so:

```
.h-page {
  font-size: 24px;
  @include breakpoint(tablet) {
    font-size: 21px;
  }
  @include breakpoint(phone) {
    font-size: 18px;
  }
}
```

Which would output the following:

```
.h-page {
  font-size: 24px;
  @media (max-width: 979px) {
    .h-page {
      font-size: 21px;
    }
  }
  @media (max-width: 480px) {
    .h-page {
      font-size: 18px;
    }
  }
}
```

But I'd like to be able to compile everything a second time in a separate stylesheet to just yield:

```
.h-page {
  font-size: 24px;
}
```

Any guidance on this is greatly appreciated. As stated above, I haven't been able to find anything on this in my research, so Stack Overflow is my last resort to see if anyone out there can provide a little insight on this.

Comment: try to look at this page http://jakearchibald.github.io/sass-ie/

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to set a variable such as `$devmode: 'responsive'`, perhaps in a config file. And then in your `breakpoint` mixin (and any others you'd like to toggle), do this:

```
@mixin breakpoint() {
  @if ($devmode == 'responsive') {
    // mixin
  }
}
```